# What am I doing wrong with this array in C?

Tags: c

I need to know how many times does "Maria" appears in this array, but when I run it, it says that it appears 51 times, and I think its only like 8

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int g;
    int i;
    const char * nombres[40] = {"Sandra Marisol","Juan Luis","Perez Luis","Carlitos","Maria","Mariana", "Carlota","Anthony",
                        "Fernando Jan","Alfonso Roche","Julieta Zacatenco","Maria de los Angeles","Laura Jessica",
                        "Andrea Maria","Jose Maria","Andres Molina","Aline Derrant","Paquito","Luisa","Ana Maria",
                        "Caleb","Luis Fernando","Mario Alberto","Paula Monica","Otoniel","Elias Primero","Maurico Enrique",
                        "Anastasia Maria","Maria Juana","Juana de Arco","Aria Montgomery""Hanna Maria","Magdalena","David Green",
                        "Florian Drake","Edward Jones","Joakin Broder","Paar","Alicia Torres","Juan Pablo"};
    for(i = 0; i>40; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", nombres[40]);
        if(nombres[i] == "Maria")
        g++;
    }
    if(g>0){
            printf("El nombre de Maria aparece %d veces.", g);
        }
        else {
            printf("El nombre de Maria NO aparece");
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post the code, not a picture of the code. If someone wanted to help you and the answer wasn’t obvious, they’d have to retype the entire program themselves.

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless, as are pictures of your entire desktop. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I´ve already edit it

Comment: Look carefully at your use of `g`. If that doesn't help, use a debugger to step through the code watching the value of `g`.

Comment: I don´t know I´m learning C, by my own, and it's different to Java, and my teacher only asks us for code but I don´t even know how to print something or the sintaxis to do it

Comment: I just told you exactly what to look at for the cause of the problem. Please read my last comment again.

Comment: thanks I´m still loking for the problem with g

Comment: OK. One more hint. Print out the value of `g` before the `for` loop. Is it what you expect? If that doesn't help, go back and ask your teacher for help, because you missed something in class.

Comment: `nombres[i] == "Maria"` this is probably not what you want to do, read about [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

Comment: `printf("%s\n", nombres[40]);` Out of bound access on the array here.

Comment: First get the basics clear,  always intiialize the count variable to 0 (in your case it's g), compare strings using "strcmp()", and learn how to use a for loop :)

Answer (score 0):

`if(nombres[i] == "Maria")`

You can't compare strings like this.  You need to use `strstr()` to look for substrings in a string.

Also,
`printf("%s\n", nombres[40]);` probably should have `i` instead of `40`.  And your comparison in the middle of your for loop above this is backwards.

And... probably more else wrong, but that is enough for me.

Comment: There's a bigger issue than this in the code posted. Not voting, just commenting. What you've pointed out wouldn't produce the issue the poster has described.

Comment: Agreed.  It is loaded with errors. `g` is clearly just getting whatever happened to be at that stack location since it isn't initialized and the for loop is never entered.

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of error..... Let's see how much I could solve..xd

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int g=0;
        int i;
        const char * nombres[40] = {"Sandra Marisol","Juan Luis","Perez Luis","Carlitos","Maria","Mariana", "Carlota","Anthony",
                            "Fernando Jan","Alfonso Roche","Julieta Zacatenco","Maria de los Angeles","Laura Jessica",
                            "Andrea Maria","Jose Maria","Andres Molina","Aline Derrant","Paquito","Luisa","Ana Maria",
                            "Caleb","Luis Fernando","Mario Alberto","Paula Monica","Otoniel","Elias Primero","Maurico Enrique",
                            "Anastasia Maria","Maria Juana","Juana de Arco","Aria Montgomery""Hanna Maria","Magdalena","David Green",
                            "Florian Drake","Edward Jones","Joakin Broder","Paar","Alicia Torres","Juan Pablo"};
        for(i = 0; i<40; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", nombres[i]);
            if(!strcmp(nombres[i],"Maria"))
            g++;
        }
        if(g>0){
                printf("El nombre de Maria aparece %d veces.", g);
            }
            else {
                printf("El nombre de Maria NO aparece");
            }

        return 0;

    }
```

Here the counter variable g was not initialized. It should be initialized to 0 otherwize it contains some garbage value.then in for loop the condition was wrong the loop was not being executed because u write I>40 here i is initialized by 0 so condition get false and loop don't run.then printf in the loop contains nombres[40] which gives a nullpointer because you last name is hombres[39].then in if condition you can't just compare string like other variable you have to use lib function which is ***strcmp*** which means string compare.
In following conditions

```
strcmp(s1,s2);
```

**

```
*if s1==s2 then it returns 0.
If s1>s2 then it returns 1
If s1<s2 it returns -1
```

---

So I wrote `!strcmp();`
***So if string matches it will return 0 and '!' Converts it to 1.***
Hope this works.kudos.

Comment: The OP does not learn by you fixing his code. Try to explain what is wrong, and how to fix it instead.

Comment: This is my second answer over here sorry for this now I havgiven brief explanation about the code errors and mistajes

Comment: Briefly explained the code an mistakes mad by the questioner. As this is my second answer over here sorry for this but sometimes you don't won't to understand you just need the answer

Comment: @harald see it now pls and give some more suggestions pls

Comment: It's better, but a bit hard to follow. My suggestions: Drop the complete code, break up the block of text into paragraphs, link to [doc of strcmp](https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead of repeating it here. Good luck!